# java encryption API + GUI

Tags: java, encryption

Is there a windows program that allows users to encrypt a file so that it can be accessed via a Java API programmatically  (i.e. to decrypt it in memory)?

I hope this makes sense.

I guess the question is twofold

(1) Is there a free Java API to access/decrypt encrypted files?
(2) Is there a free program that allows you to encrypt files supported by the API?

Thanks.

Best wishes,

Christian

Comment: Good question, I am also intersted. I solve this issue with hashed values in embedded database with GUI, but I actually don't decrypt it back, just compare to hash values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[BouncyCastle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/) is a good free library for cryptography in Java (and in C#). It's actively maintained (unlike [Cryptix](http://www.cryptix.org/) since 2005 apparently). It has a package for OpenPGP support, with which you should be able to do what you want. In addition, it's probably worth looking at its [resources page](http://www.bouncycastle.org/resources.html), which lists a few tools that have been built on top of it (including related to OpenPGP).

Answer (score 1):

There is a JCE provider for PGP available from [cryptix](http://www.cryptix.org/). There are plenty of PGP programs available for windows and other platforms, including integration in email programs.

Answer (score 0):

[Jasypt](http://www.jasypt.org/) is a Java package that simplifies encryption in Java. It works with either the built-in JCE provider or others (like BouncyCastle). There are basic [command line](http://www.jasypt.org/cli.html) apps included with it that you could use as a base for your own program.